# Python Gensim how to make WMD similarity run faster with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, gensim

I am trying to run gensim WMD similarity faster. Typically, this is what is in the docs:
Example corpus:

```
    my_corpus = ["Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications",
>>>              "A survey of user opinion of computer system response time",
>>>              "The EPS user interface management system",
>>>              "System and human system engineering testing of EPS",
>>>              "Relation of user perceived response time to error measurement",
>>>              "The generation of random binary unordered trees",
>>>              "The intersection graph of paths in trees",
>>>              "Graph minors IV Widths of trees and well quasi ordering",
>>>              "Graph minors A survey"]

my_query = 'Human and artificial intelligence software programs'
my_tokenized_query =['human','artificial','intelligence','software','programs']

model = a trained word2Vec model on about 100,000 documents similar to my_corpus.
model = Word2Vec.load(word2vec_model)
```

---

```
from gensim import Word2Vec
from gensim.similarities import WmdSimilarity

def init_instance(my_corpus,model,num_best):
    instance = WmdSimilarity(my_corpus, model,num_best = 1)
    return instance
instance[my_tokenized_query]
```

the best matched document is `"Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications"` which is great.

However the function `instance` above takes an extremely long time. So I thought of breaking up the corpus into `N` parts and then doing `WMD` on each with `num_best = 1`, then at the end of it, the part with the max score will be the most similar.

```
    from multiprocessing import Process, Queue ,Manager

    def main( my_query,global_jobs,process_tmp):
        process_query = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(my_query)

        def worker(num,process_query,return_dict):  
            instance=init_instance\
(my_corpus[num*chunk+1:num*chunk+chunk], model,1)
            x = instance[process_query][0][0]
            y = instance[process_query][0][1]
            return_dict[x] = y
        manager = Manager()
        return_dict = manager.dict()

        for num in range(num_workers):
            process_tmp = Process(target=worker, args=(num,process_query,return_dict))
            global_jobs.append(process_tmp)
            process_tmp.start()
        for proc in global_jobs:
            proc.join()

        return_dict = dict(return_dict)
        ind = max(return_dict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
        print corpus[ind]
        >>> "Graph minors A survey"
```

The problem I have with this is that, even though it outputs something, it doesn't give me a good similar query from my corpus even though it gets the max similarity of all the parts.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Make a MCVE, missing `my_query, my_corpus, model, my_tokenized_query`.

Comment: Hi @stovfl, updated.

Comment: Did you try using a special python compiler such as pypy ?

Comment: @macdrai nope, would it have affected?

Answer (score 5):

> **Comment**: chunk is a static variable: e.g. chunk = 600 ...

If you define `chunk` static, then you have to compute `num_workers`.

```
10001 / 600 = 16,6683333333 = 17 num_workers
```

It's common **to use not** more `process` than `cores` you have.
If you have `17 cores`, that's ok.

`cores` are static, therefore you should:

```
num_workers = os.cpu_count()
chunk = chunksize(my_corpus, num_workers)
```

---

1. Not the same result, changed to:

   ```
   #process_query = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(my_query)
   process_query = my_tokenized_query
   ```
2. All `worker` results Index 0..n.
   Therefore, `return_dict[x]` could be overwritten from last worker with same Index having lower value. The Index in return_dict is **NOT** the same as Index in `my_corpus`. Changed to:

   ```
   #return_dict[x] = y
   return_dict[ (num * chunk)+x ] = y
   ```
3. Using **`+1`** in chunk size computing, will skip that first *Document*.
   I don't know how you compute `chunk`, consider this example:

   ```
   def chunksize(iterable, num_workers):
       c_size, extra = divmod(len(iterable), num_workers)
       if extra:
           c_size += 1
       if len(iterable) == 0:
           c_size = 0
       return c_size

   #Usage
   chunk = chunksize(my_corpus, num_workers)
   ...
   #my_corpus_chunk = my_corpus[num*chunk+1:num*chunk+chunk]
   my_corpus_chunk = my_corpus[num * chunk:(num+1) * chunk]
   ```

> **Results**: 10 cycle, Tuple=(Index worker num=0, Index worker num=1)
>
> > With `multiprocessing`, with `chunk=5`:
> >     02,09:(3, 8), 01,03:(3, 5):
> >     System and human system engineering testing of EPS
> >     04,06,07:(0, 8), 05,08:(0, 5), 10:(0, 7):
> >     Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications
> >
> > Without `multiprocessing`, with `chunk=5`:
> >     01:(3, 6), 02:(3, 5), 05,08,10:(3, 7), 07,09:(3, 8):
> >     System and human system engineering testing of EPS
> >     03,04,06:(0, 5):
> >     Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications
> >
> > Without `multiprocessing`, without chunking:
> >     01,02,03,04,06,07,08:(3, -1):
> >     System and human system engineering testing of EPS
> >     05,09,10:(0, -1):
> >     Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: chunk is a static variable: e.g. `chunk = 600` would it have affected much?

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 2.7:
I used threading instead of multi-processing. 
In the WMD-Instance creation thread, I do something like this:

```
    wmd_instances = []
    if wmd_instance_count > len(wmd_corpus):
        wmd_instance_count = len(wmd_corpus)
    chunk_size = int(len(wmd_corpus) / wmd_instance_count)
    for i in range(0, wmd_instance_count):
        if i == wmd_instance_count -1:
            wmd_instance = WmdSimilarity(wmd_corpus[i*chunk_size:], wmd_model, num_results)
        else:
            wmd_instance = WmdSimilarity(wmd_corpus[i*chunk_size:chunk_size], wmd_model, num_results)
        wmd_instances.append(wmd_instance)
    wmd_logic.setWMDInstances(wmd_instances, chunk_size)
```

'wmd_instance_count' is the number of threads to use to search. I also remember the chunk-size. Then, when I want to search for something, I start "wmd_instance_count"-threads to search for and they return found sims:

```
def perform_query_for_job_on_instance(wmd_logic, wmd_instances, query, jobID, instance):
    wmd_instance = wmd_instances[instance]
    sims = wmd_instance[query]
    wmd_logic.set_mt_thread_result(jobID, instance, sims)
```

'wmd_logic' is the instance of a class that then does this:

```
def set_mt_thread_result(self, jobID, instance, sims):
    res = []
    #
    # We need to scale the found ids back to our complete corpus size...
    #
    for sim in sims:
        aSim = (int(sim[0] + (instance * self.chunk_size)), sim[1])
        res.append(aSim)
```

I know, the code isn't nice, but it works. It uses 'wmd_instance_count' threads to find results, I aggregate them and then choose the top-10 or something like that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The line: wmd_instance = `WmdSimilarity(wmd_corpus[i*chunk_size:chunk_size], wmd_model, num_results)` should actually be: wmd_instance = `WmdSimilarity(wmd_corpus[i*chunk_size:(i+1) * chunk_size], wmd_model, num_results)`